# Java: How to create a new frame with the details of a selected object?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface, awt

I am trying to create a simple GUI with swing for a bank application and I do not know how to create a new frame that is somehow linked to a certain object.

[image]

When I press "Bank Details" I would like to open a new frame that looks exactly like this one but has the list of clients of the selected bank. And there I would like to edit the list of clients of the selected bank by adding/deleting them. How could I do this? Any example code would be appreciated.

Comment: Conceptually it simply comes down to [Passing information to a method or a constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Comment: 1) See also [How to create great screenshots?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99734/155831) 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) *"I would like to open a new frame that looks exactly like this"* I would recommend improving the look of that one before replicating that look! The `GridLayout` means both sides get equal space, but it would be better if extra space were assigned to the list. Use a `BorderLayout` instead. The list can go in the `CENTER` & buttons in the `LINE_END`. Further, the `BoxLayout` makes ..

Comment: Since you haven’t shown us what code you’ve written, it’s hard to know where to start.  Have you written a `Bank` class?  Does it have a method with a name like getClients or something similar?  Do you know what you want this new window to look like?

Comment: .. the buttons appear crowded. There are a number of different strategies that could be pursued for adding white space for those. 4) *"Any example code would be appreciated."* SO is not a code generation machine.

Comment: get a help from [*An example of JList with a DefaultListModel*](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AnexampleofJListwithaDefaultListModel.htm) and for detailed, you can show the list containing class details through frame, dialog or optionpane as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

An easy approach would be to pass a String to the constructor that is the name of the frame you are currently working on.

As for inserting data to the `JComboBox` it should be done by conditions.

A simple code to solve the problem would be like this:

```
public Bank(String name){
    base_name = name; // base_name is a private variable to save the data
    frame.setTitle(base_name);
    switch (base_name){
        case "bank":    
            jComboBox1.addItem("bank1");
            jComboBox1.addItem("bank2");
            break;
        case "department":
            jComboBox1.addItem("dept1");
            jComboBox1.addItem("dept1");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Unrecognized name");
    }
}
```

Now all you have to do inside details click action is (if you clicked details for bank):

```
BankFrame frame = new BankFrame("bank");  
frame.setVisible(true);
```